# Re-fit a decision tree to add a layer

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am wondering if there is a way to re-use an existing DecisionTreeClassifier to add another layer.

My scenario is the following:

- I have some data (data array **X** with corresponding labels **y**) for classification
- I train a **DecisionTreeClassifier** with `max_depth=1` on my (X,y) data.
- While I am not satisfied with my classifier:

  - Re-use the same classifier with the same data, to add leaves at the bottom of my tree, therefore increasing the depth by 1 (It's important that I keep the same tree, I am just adding a layer of leaves at the bottom, I am not retraining a new DecisionTree with `max_depth=n+1`)

Is there a way to do this with scikit-learn? Or with other classifiers, like a neural network, can you train your neural network with, say, 10 epochs, then if it is not accurate enough, re-train it with another 10 epochs, and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Short answer :*

**No**, you can't.

*Long answer :*

A **DecisionTreeClassifier** is not meant to be fitted again. 
As you can see in the source code [tree.py](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/tree.py) at line 350, the internal tree is built using some class inheriting from TreeBuilder. This class is from the cpython file [_tree.py](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/_tree.pyx). You can still try to tweak this class by copy / pasting chunks of its code ... I wouldn't recommend it because it is pain in the neck and it is not likely to work at all.

Hope you will find (or found) another solution and will share it with us :)